# Fetch Data in Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

is there any way in Firestore to get List of Data in single array ,, for example ..in Firebase RealTimeDatabase we get List of Data by calling single value instead of using ForEachLoop...for Example in realtimeDatabase we get value by :

```
var messageArray  : [Message] = [ ] ()

Database.database().reference.child("messages").observe( .childAdded , with : { (snapshot) in 
    let snapShotValue = snapshot.value

    let text = snapShotValue["text"] as! String
    let username = snapShotValue["username"] as! String

    let message = Message( text ,username)

    self.messageArray.append(message)
}
```

but in Firestore we have to used ForLoop and that is Ok but in some cases i have to used  RealTimeDatabase option in Firestore.....For Example in Firestore we used:

```
FireStore.firestore().collection("messages").getDocuments { (snapshot , error ) in 

    for document in snaphot.document {

        let data = document.data( )
        let text = data["text"] as! String
        let username = data["username"] as! String


        let message = Message( text , username)
        self.messageArray.append(message)
     }
}
```

So is there any way to get Data of Firestore as whole ObjectArray similar to FireBase RealTimeDatabase

Answer (score 0):

You can store all of the object data in an array like this:

`let allData = snapshot.documents.compactMap { $0.data() }`